# Custom profile curve with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

With Geometry Nodes I am able to create a curve with specific points.

[image: curve with specific points]

Now I would change the traditional curve profile for a custom one.

[image: custom one]

How can I define one like this?

[image: Traditional Geometry Nodes for a curve.]

Traditional Geometry Nodes for a curve.

Thanks for your time and help ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead using the GN 'Curve Circle' you can use 'Curve on Points' combined with 'Instance on points' to fill the curve with instances of a mesh.
[image: Result and GN]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to set the radius on the bezier curve before handing it to the curve-to-mesh node. Input to this radius can be a function that will provide your "dents". Here are the relevant edits to your blend.[image]

Which gives you this,
[image]

I use a clamped sine wave for the dents, obviously not perfect, but you get the idea. Note that you need more resolution in the bezier curve.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I never thought of solving the problem this way.

Anyway, I would have liked to be able to control the result more in order to put shapes more iregular.

Sorry for my awfull english :(